# Intersection of branded types

Tags: typescript

Under `typescript 3.7.5` I had these types:

```
interface Branding<BrandT> { readonly __brand: BrandT; }
type Brand<T, BrandT> = T & Branding<BrandT>;

interface SortableRegion { start: number; end: number; }
type SortedRegionArray<T extends SortableRegion> = Brand<T[], 'sorted'>;
type SortedUniqueRegionArray<T extends SortableRegion> = Brand<SortedRegionArray<T>, 'unique'>;
```

and the type `SortedUniqueRegionArray` evaluated to:

`type SortedUniqueRegionArray<T extends SortableRegion> = T[] & Branding<"sorted"> & Branding<"unique">`

and so I had the functionality of a sorted and unique array could be assigned to a sorted one but not the other way around.

Under `typescript 4.3.2` the type `SortedUniqueRegionArray` evaluates to:

`type SortedUniqueRegionArray<T extends SortableRegion> = never`

and as a result a lot of code doesn't compile.

How can I properly intersect branded types in typescript?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#code/PQKhAIFUGcFMBNwCMCe4BCAnAhgO0QC4D24AttpgNbjbgEoAOs4AlrjeJrNvNkgDbMA7thQA6cCGABYAFCwAHgyKYCrXAViYAZtgDGzLHnhsA5gB4j%20ACoA%20cAG9O3eEVz80AfU9Ic%20AFwYfvDWANzgAL5yoBAAwlzYmhwARL7GCMngAG5a0Cxu4ETaHPRMEtaMsADKepgsDGpCbgDkatj8-ERCrKQM-Cx6LGp6bjmYeQXEdAAWLNB0lZIy8koqaqWGwebWADRBxnbgALzg1uAAZPv4ZpbBdqFycorKquqaOvrMVWt8ggBKsFM%20XYTmgBAoBECuAArqQkFpwrAAuAYXCEZEnqtXhtwN9VAgAUC3ABBTA4FDbcCKTT4eZ48ECWCE4H2E5WeDbADaAF09s1oGsEM1bA8Vi91ot6QhILgWABHaFMwHA0nkynUpHwOk-RnMtysq4cqXwPW4VWiba2PnQ2UK2DC0VyQRtQLG03min035Kom4A08mjzG2UXBddjYbX4k3Kklki1e3Uxv2i53IV2C%20Ay%20WK91xz06-5J-3cwPgYOhoThyOaTO2nNJj3mBOF30ix6yWgnJCipDHGg9vu0CO4jNZu25tXNn0sx2yIA)

Comment: The later version of typescript is correct about this type. If your code used to work, it's only because types are erased at runtime and have no actual effect on the correctness of your program. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I said the code doesnt work I meant it doesnt compile. I would like to have objects of `SortableRegion` that are sometimes `sorted` and other times `sorted` and `unique`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a single branding value.
Since a type like this will always result in type `never`:

```
let value: "unique" & "sorted"; // type of value = never
```

However, you could introduce multiple branding values.
In your case, one for uniqueness and one for sorting.

*Note: I have never used/needed something like this, so I don't know how well it will work long term or if it's even a good idea to consider it.*

Expanding on your example:

```
type MultiBranding<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `__brand_${string & Property}`]: Type[Property]
};
type MultiBrand<T, BrandT> = T & MultiBranding<BrandT>;

// Examples
export interface SortableRegion { start: number; end: number; }

type Unique<T extends SortableRegion> = MultiBrand<T[], { uniqueness: "unique" }>
type Sorted<T extends SortableRegion> = MultiBrand<T[], { sorting: "sorted" }>

let sortedArray: Sorted<SortableRegion> = [] as unknown as Sorted<SortableRegion>;
let uniqueArray: Unique<SortableRegion> = [] as unknown as Unique<SortableRegion>;

// This fancyArray represents the goal you're trying to achieve
let fancyArray: Sorted<SortableRegion> & Unique<SortableRegion> = [] as unknown as Sorted<SortableRegion> & Unique<SortableRegion>;

sortedArray = unsortedArray; // fails
sortedArray = uniqueArray; // fails
fancyArray = sortedArray; // fails
fancyArray = uniqueArray; // fails

sortedArray = fancyArray; // succeeds
uniqueArray = fancyArray; // succeeds

// For completeness
type Unsorted<T extends SortableRegion> = MultiBrand<T[], { sorting: "unsorted" }>
type NotUnique<T extends SortableRegion> = MultiBrand<T[], { uniqueness: "not-unique" }>

let unsortedArray: Unsorted<SortableRegion> = [] as unknown as Unsorted<SortableRegion>;
let notUniqueArray: NotUnique<SortableRegion> = [] as unknown as NotUnique<SortableRegion>;

unsortedArray = fancyArray; // fails
notUniqueArray = fancyArray; // fails
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#code/DYUwLgBAlgtgDgewM5KgI1ALggIgK4B2UAjniDhAGS5IIBOYIAJjgNwCwAUFyAB6INoBRnQBmAQwDGICAGV6YcRhAAlEAHMoCAhADeEJIobYCeGGhB1WEEASYmzFqxAC+XLmACecGQFk8wGBQAEJ04nZQBOoAPAAq3iAAfBAAvHpcEJkQANoACnQIPgyeQhAA1iCeCKIQ8T4Q4kgQAAYA+q1oYXatACS6hnSR6lQQ+YWWXi7NALrYdSB5BUVe01wuHJxe9f6BIV1McQA0EKHhTLHJabEjO0GnEVHR9+eJGx4JEACqRKQgcTa8Rh2JryBhKUBqTTaS4QW57M5xbLTY76QgkMgEEAobD4H5kCguRLveqgxgHa58IFMEEKcGqDRaAgwuHPRHIvQGBRDHG0BjMAlE7icUCQXlkgCCdDCnmwpOY0VJdMhjJhSIaTUIZQICAA7jpGnIFPLFcpldCNiKIGjfpLpdhvui-iaIQzoakctN1VaCFrdfqmg7fgraabXUyLeAIBICJJPLbxDLDXyDs76VCmSNA2Rg2DQ+nVZ6DZrtXqvXKUyGXfnM3inZW0yq3pwxcx4yU0oQW0w29YAPS9qPiKDAJBcLtt93Wsg9iD9wfD0ecaOxidpcdShN9gcSBdcZdxjft72Omdzncj9zNo3dw-u-engdIPCSaTMRdTkCrwcxg-SrcGZ9X2pS8thkb4u3+SlbGpJNFDzFV3RZfY2RRTkGG5XBO2vAUuEtLDkzbe0CAg1MzQzNI1SLH0S39L5iOvHM4KrRsQI+AA5BAwCzP4KUBaCaVzZi3TSJCEViJFUI-TFsVwbUwAAWg-HDhUjOTuMIiAOK42tGKVMMCy9Ys-S9LTuN0+DzUvfCJVvNJ70Pf9z0XNTay-ey-1nbchxHIA)

*Note: If you only have a limited number of combinations for unique/sorted, then I would consider creating a type that represents each case and seeing how it evolves.*